# python: 'numpy.int32' object is not iterable when using reduce on a numpy list

Tags: python, numpy

I am new to python programming. when using reduce() function on a numpy array (like this code):

```
import numpy as np
from functools import reduce
x = np.arange(1, 5)    
y = list(reduce(lambda s, t: s + t, x))
```

I receive this error:

```
TypeError: 'numpy.int32' object is not iterable
```

I tested the same codes for map() function and had no error:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.arange(1, 5)    
z = list(map(lambda s: s if s%2 == 0  else None, x))
```

How can I use reduce function for a numpy array?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure you want to use `reduce`? One strength of numpy is vectorized functions, which will be much faster than `reduce`.

Comment: On one hand, this isn't an efficient way to interact with NumPy arrays. On the other hand, I'm baffled that it fails.

Comment: `reduce` returns an int/float. You are trying to cast it to a `list`

Comment: ...oh. I feel silly for missing that now.

Comment: (Use `numpy.sum`, though.)

Comment: or even `sum(range(5))`

Comment: yes i can use numpy methods, but it is just a typical example! I want to test whether I can use reduce on numpy array or not

Comment: "when using reduce() function on a numpy array" **don't do that**

Answer (score 0):

I found my fault!

reduce() function a single value not a list.
So this code,

```
y = reduce(lambda s, t: s + t, x)
```

has no error.